# Centering 3 images below a main image

Tags: html, css

Ok, so I am not a developer, and have some minor HTML experience. We are a small company, and I have tasked with creating an html file with 1 main image and 3 smaller images below it.  I have that figured out here mostly:  https://jsfiddle.net/cekjf79u/  however, the 3 images below are way too big, and I need them to span evenly on image 1.  Again, I got to this point by reading some  answers here, and could use a tiny bit more help to complete this project. Thank you in advance!

```css
.container{text-align:center;}
.container img{
  display:inline-block;
  width:30%;
  margin:0 1% 0 1%;
  }
```

```html
<img src="https://c.na43.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=0150G000007uVGN&oid=00DF0000000Bq7x&lastMod=1507305397000" width="50%" height="50%">
<br>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://c.na43.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=0150G000007uVG8&oid=00DF0000000Bq7x&lastMod=1507305292000" >


<img src="https://c.na43.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=0150G000007uVGD&oid=00DF0000000Bq7x&lastMod=1507305314000">




  <img src="https://c.na43.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=0150G000007uVGI&oid=00DF0000000Bq7x&lastMod=1507305333000">
```

Comment: Do you want the images below to line up with the edges of the main image?

Comment: Yes, thanks for looking at this for me!

Comment: you can use display:block for the first image, put them all together, mind the white-space, set width to the last 3. eventually set size or max-size to the first one to control the lot. https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/WZMpRv?editors=1100

Comment: ..... float can also be used https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vedxdP?editors=1100 .. not too sure about what expected with height. Can you clarify your question ?

Answer (score 1):

In code below, you are possibility to add many small images and all will be aligned correctly.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
  <img class="big-thumbnail" src="https://c.na43.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=0150G000007uVGN&oid=00DF0000000Bq7x&lastMod=1507305397000" alt="">
  <div class="small-thumbnails">
    <img src="https://c.na43.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=0150G000007uVG8&oid=00DF0000000Bq7x&lastMod=1507305292000" alt="">
    <img src="https://c.na43.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=0150G000007uVGD&oid=00DF0000000Bq7x&lastMod=1507305314000" alt="">
    <img src="https://c.na43.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=0150G000007uVGI&oid=00DF0000000Bq7x&lastMod=1507305333000" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container .big-thumbnail {
  width: 50%;
}
.container .small-thumbnails {
  width:50%;
  //text-align: center; // You can center all small images
}
.small-thumbnails img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 1%;
}
```

or look in jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/cekjf79u/10/

Comment: Perfect!  Worked like a charm.  Thank you both so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can place a larger div around all four divs. This will determine the maximum width. I used 500px because I don't know what your site looks like but if all 4 images are already in a div you don't need the div I called main.

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
    <img id="big" src="https://c.na43.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=0150G000007uVGN&oid=00DF0000000Bq7x&lastMod=1507305397000">

    <img class="small" src="https://c.na43.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=0150G000007uVGN&oid=00DF0000000Bq7x&lastMod=1507305397000" >

    <img class="small" src="https://c.na43.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=0150G000007uVGN&oid=00DF0000000Bq7x&lastMod=1507305397000">

    <img class="small" src="https://c.na43.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=0150G000007uVGN&oid=00DF0000000Bq7x&lastMod=1507305397000">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main {
  width: 500px;
  padding: 0px; 
}
#big {
  width: 100%;
}
.small {
  float: left;
  display:inline;
  width: 33.333%;
}
```